# current_user method not found (Rails, Devise, Cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using Rails 3.2, Devise and Cancan for an application with 3 user categories: Companies, Customers and Admins.

My problem is that I get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<HomeController:0xb4fd217c>
```

In HomeController I have:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_customer!
  load_and_authorize_resource :class => false

  def index
        render 'index'
    end

end
```

Also, in the view:

```
- content_for :title, 'Home'
= link_to('Logout', destroy_customer_session_path, :method => :delete)
```

I am not calling current_user anywhere in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your "authenticate_customer!" method look like?

Comment: It's from devise, I didn't implement it.

Comment: Are you using CanCan or some other gem that interacts with Devise?  I mention CanCan specifically because you may have to create a `current_ability` method in your `ApplicationController`, per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/598).

Comment: Note that in general, anywhere that `current_user` is referenced will need to be changed to `current_customer`, but you say you're not referencing `current_user` anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

CanCan makes two assumptions about your application.

- You have an Ability class which defines the permissions.
- You have a current_user method in the controller which returns the current user model.

You can override both of these by defining the current_ability method in your ApplicationController.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults

Comment: I will apprecciate some feedback. Did my answer solved your problem?